# C++ problemas com overloading operator+ (undefined reference to 'operator+(...))

Tags: c++, operadores

Estou com problemas para fazer o overloading do operador + em C++. Alguém faz ideia do que está errado?

Para realizar os unit tests estou utilizando o googletest no Ubuntu.
(queria fazer isso para deixar o código mais limpo)

Código:

---- vector.cpp -----

```
vector<double> operator+(const vector<double>& r1, const vector<double>& r2)
{
  double size;
  size = r1.size();

  if(r1.size() != r2.size()) {
    cerr << "Vector Subtraction Error: Vectors with different dimensions!" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  vector<double> r3 (size,0);

  for(int i = 0; i < int(r3.size()); i++)
    r3[i] = r1[i] + r2[i];

  return r3;
}
```

--- vectorTest.cpp ---

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <vector>
#include "../src/vector.h"

using namespace std;

TEST (SumVectorTest, vector)
{
  vector<double> r1(2);
  vector<double> r2(2);
  vector<double> r3(2);

  r1[0] = 2; r2[0] = 3;
  r1[1] = 3; r2[1] = 17;
  r3 = r1 + r2;

  EXPECT_EQ(r3[0], 5);
  EXPECT_EQ(r3[1], 20);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

--- terminal ---

```
$ g++ vectorTest.cpp -lgtest
/tmp/ccNRp61Z.o: In function `SumVectorTest_vector_Test::TestBody()':
vectorTest.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `operator+(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

PS: Eu estava utilizando o mesmo código em um Mac OS X e ele não me retornava erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem dois arquivos de códigos que precisam ser compilador para gerar um executável, mas só está compilando um deles (vectorTest.cpp). Uma solução bem rápida, seria incluir os dois arquivos em linha de comando, por exemplo:

```
g++ vectorTest.cpp vector.cpp -lgtest
```

Uma solução de longo prazo, é especificar um script de compilação (para ser usado em um make, ou cmake, por exemplo)

Comment: Deu certo :) muito obrigado!